# Open Intel XDK links in system browser?

Tags: android, jquery, html, browser, intel-xdk

I've been working on an HTML5 app in the Intel XDK lately and part of the app is buttons that link to external websites. I'm having a problem with the apps opening in the same window, which then causes the user to get stuck in the browser. I'm using the Jquery mobile framework currently. I constantly call the link to open in a "_blank" target, and have also tried several other things such as "window.load". What do I do to get this to work? The app has to work with android and iOS. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Cordova inAppBrowser plugin, see the docs here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser You will want to use _system target with it.